# What numbers are anti-divisors of $105$?

Tags: number-theory

I don't get the mean of [anti-divisor](https://oeis.org/A066272/a066272a.html) right.

By [this](https://oeis.org/A066272/list) page, the number of anti-divisors of $105$ is $9$. However, what numbers are anti-divisors of $105$?
Would you teach me the process of the calculate of it?

**P.S.:**

The numbers are [$2, 6, 10, 11, 14, 19, 30, 42, 70$](http://web.archive.org/web/20060923020040/http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~perry/maths/antidivisors.htm).

By Daniel Fischer♦'s comment, I try to calculate the numbers.

```
# Ruby
(2..105).each{|i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    p i if 105 % i == i / 2
  else
    p i if (105 % i == (i - 1) / 2) || (105 % i == (i + 1) / 2)
  end
}
```

Output

```
2
6
10
11
14
19
30
42
70
```

Comment: @Roby5 Since $105 = 6\cdot 17 + 3$, $17$ is not an anti-divisor of $105$. Nor is $4$, since $105 = 26\cdot 4 + 1$, or $18$ ($105 = 5\cdot 18 + 15$).

Comment: @DanielFischer How are the odd and even anti-divisor derived from the simplest definition of anti-divisor provided in the above mentioned link?

Comment: An even number $2 \leqslant 2m \leqslant n$ is an anti-divisor of $n$ if and only if $m \mid n$ and $2m \nmid n$. An odd number $3 \leqslant 2m+1 \leqslant n$ is an anti-divisor of $n$ if and only if $(2m+1) \mid (2n-1)$ or $(2m+1) \mid (2n+1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer By simplest definition, I mean this: An anti-divisor is a non-divisor such that doesn't divide the number in the most unbiased way possible. For example, we say $42$ is an anti-divisor of $63$, as $42$ surrounds $63$ with a gap of $21$ on either side. $41$ on the other hand, has gaps of $22$ and $18$, so the gap of $22$ is larger than the $18$.$ 41$ is called a biased non-divisor of $63.$

Comment: @Manyama No, that's not it. The definition of an anti-divisor is roughly "the remainder of $n$ modulo $k$ is as close to $k/2$ as an integer can be". Plus the restriction that it be between $1$ and $n$ (both exclusive).

Comment: @Roby5 "in the most unbiased way possible" translates to $n \equiv m \pmod{2m}$ for $k = 2m$ even, and $n \equiv m \pmod{2m+1}$ or $n \equiv m+1 \pmod{2m+1}$ for $k = 2m+1$ odd. If you look at these conditions for a moment, you can see that they are equivalent to what I wrote above.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the page you've linked you need to do a slightly different calculation based on if the $k$ you are considering to be an anti-divisor is even or odd.

**Even Anti-Divisors**

For even anti-divisors you are looking for integer solutions of $x$ to the equation: $$k\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=105$$

Rearranging this gives:

$$k=\frac{210}{1+2x}$$

So calculate all the odd divisors of $210$ (which are: $3,5,7,15,21,35,105$) and hence work out $k$: $$\frac{210}{3}=70,\frac{210}{5}=42,\frac{210}{7}=30,\frac{210}{15}=14,\frac{210}{21}=10,\frac{210}{35}=6,\frac{210}{105}=2$$

**Odd Anti-Divisors**

For odd anit-divisors you are looking for integer solutions of $x$ to the equations: $$k\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=105\pm\frac{1}{2}$$

Rearranging these gives:

$$k=\frac{209}{1+2x}$$

and

$$k=\frac{211}{1+2x}$$

So like in the even case find the odd divisors of 209 and 211 which are: $209:\ 11,19$; $211:\ $prime

This gives you the final two anti-divisors: $$\frac{209}{11}=19,\frac{209}{19}=11$$

So the anti-divisors are: $2, 6, 10, 11, 14, 19, 30, 42, 70$

Answer (score 1):

For $k$ even, $k$ is an anti-divisor of $105$ if $105\equiv \frac k2 \pmod k$.  This yields $2,6,10,14,30,42,70$.  For $k$ odd, $k$ is an anti-divisor of $15$ if $105 \equiv \frac {k-1}2 \pmod k$ or $105 \equiv \frac {k+1}2 \pmod k$.  This yields $11,19$.  I just made an Excel sheet that checked all the numbers.  Copy down is wonderful.